# Mono embedding: How to access type of a property in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, mono, embed

i am embedding Mono to use it for scripting in my application. I would like to access properties. To make sure the type my application expects is equivalent to the type of some property i need to check the property's type.

My problem is, that i have not found a way to access the property's type.

For fields there is a single function namely `mono_field_get_type`. I know how to get the signature of a the property's getter-/setter-method, but i could not find any function to access for example the return type of the getter-method.

Can you tell me how to retrieve the type of a property?

For those who like to see some code:

```
MonoType* MonoScriptPropertyVariableSource::getType(MonoObject* instance, MonoProperty* prop)
{
    // MonoMethod* method = mono_property_get_get_method(prop);
    // MonoMethodSignature* sig = mono_method_get_signature(method, 0, 0);
    // and now? ...

    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return mono_signature_get_return_type (sig);

Other accessors for MonoSignature are in metadata.h.